# Why doesnt pointer dereference work without assigning it first?

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior, dereference

```
int main() {
    
    char *x;
    *x = 'h';

    printf("%p, %c", &x, *x); // prints nothing
    return 0;
}
```

When I print the address of x I get a real hex address. But I can't print the x after assigning it. Why can't I assign a value without doing this:

```
int main() {
    
    char *x;
    char y = 'y';
    x = &y;
    *x = 'h';

    printf("%p, %c", &x, *x); //prints address and 'h'
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What piece of memory do you think `x` points to in the first code fragment?

Comment: The same reason you can't use the value of any other variable before assigning it first.

Answer (score 3):

After this declaration

```
char *x;
```

the pointer (with automatic storage duration) has an indeterminate value and does not point to a valid object. So dereferencing it results in undefined behavior.

As for this cpde

```
char *x;
char y = 'y';
x = &y;
*x = 'h';
```

then in fact using the pointer `x` you are changing the valid object `y`.

```
x = &y;
*x = 'h';
```

In essence it is the same as just to write

```
y = 'h';
```